# MYSQL statement will not recognise _POST variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

Ive created a page that lists existing hardware transactions ('else' clause below) and filters the transactions based on criteria associated with a specific row ('If' clause). The Else clause displays fine, but when I enter Criteria (e.g. Mouse)and select a Filter (e.g. device) that I know match in the database, no results are shown, when there should be.

The frustrating part is that when I change line 12 to:

```
WHERE device = '$criteria' //This will work
```

For some reason the original code wont work even though the variable $filter equals the string "device".

Please someone help, this seems like a bug to me :(

PHP Code:

```
function display_transactions() {
    //Display Transactions table
    GLOBAL $transactions;
    GLOBAL $db;
    try {
        if (isset($_POST['submit_criteria'])) { 
            GLOBAL $transactions_sql;
            $filter = $_POST['filter-by'];
            $criteria = $_POST['text_criteria'];
            $transactions_sql = "SELECT device, quantity, transaction_type, ticket_id, region, username, datetime
                                 FROM transactions
                                 WHERE '$filter' = '$criteria'
                                  ";
        } else {
            $transactions_sql = 'SELECT device, quantity, transaction_type, ticket_id, region, username, datetime
                                 FROM transactions
                                 ORDER BY datetime DESC';
            echo "UNFILTERED!";
         }
        $transactions = $db->query($transactions_sql);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

HTML page:

```
<?php display_transactions() ?>
<?php while($row = $transactions->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['device']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['transaction_type']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ticket_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['region']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If filter is supposed to be a column name, then it shouldn't be in quotes (`'`); if anything, it should be in backticks (`\``)

Comment: But it's not safe to inject $_POST values directly into SQL statements, make sure that you whitelist device values, and try using bind variables for the criteria value

Comment: Filter you input before using it in a SQL! Actually, filter it wherever! Use prepared statements and PDO.

Comment: Or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on every value, even the column names, which should indeed be enclosed with backticks like Mark said.